Why doesn't work autocomplete journalctl in debian?
I type a command in CentOS:
sudo journalctl -xe --unit ss

After that, i press Tab and see in the console:
sudo journalctl -xe --unit sshd.service


I type a command in Debian:
sudo journalctl -xe --unit ss

After that, i press Tab and ... and nothing happens:
sudo journalctl -xe --unit ss


Why doesn't work autocomplete journalctl in Debian?

test if autocomplete is installed which is usually not the case iirc

bash-completion is installed and worked

To resolve the problem, you must add the user to the "systemd-journal" group:
sudo usermod -aG systemd-journal $USER

Then logout and login or restart the computer.

This is exactly what I need. Run command, exit terminal and login again. Everything will work as expected.
